# How can I convert this bits operation code from java to objective-c?

Tags: java, objective-c, bit-manipulation

Code in java:

```
byte x = new Integer((version << 6) | (padding << 5)
            | (extension << 4) | cc).byteValue();
```

I need this in objective-c

I tried `uint8_t x = (version << 6 ) | (padding << 5) | (extension <<4) | cc);`

The java statement returns `-128`, while my approach returns `128`

Comment: Isn't uint means unsigned?

Comment: Well java bytes are signed. But don't worry, -128 and 128 are secretly the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use signed type instead of unsigned: `uint8_t` -> `int8_t`.

Why do you get `128`? There's no negative numbers in unsigned integers, so you can imagine it like this `-128 = 0 - 128 = (0 - 1) - 127 = 255 - 127 = 128` (`0 - 1 = 255` for unsigned 1-byte integer, which range is `[0; 255]`)

You can also read `byte` [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and C data-types [docs](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html)